# Circular import confusion

Tags: python, python-2.7

I have three files:

1) one.py

```
from two import test

print(test)
```

2) two.py

```
test = [1, 2]

import three

print(test)
```

3) three.py

```
from two import test

test.append(3)
```

When I run the command `python two.py`, I get:

```
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
```

When I run the command `python one.py`, I get:

```
[1, 2, 3]
[1, 2, 3]
```

Could anyone, please, explain me why I get this output?

Comment: I'm immensely curious as to what your use case is.

Comment: @TheSoundDefense Thank you for pointing out my mistake.

I was reading article about flask project organization (http://flask.pocoo.org/docs/patterns/packages/#simple-packages). They have similar code there.

Comment: I understand the behavior of `python two.py`, but I don't understand how the new value of `test` makes it all the way to `one.py`. Don't want to give a half-answer :/

Comment: @TheSoundDefense If the answer is not too long, please, share your wisdom with me :) I think your answer will help me.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The deeper I dive into this rabbit hole, the crazier this gets. After playing around with this for a bit, I think I have some idea of what the heck is going on here, though I'm still unclear on some of the why.

There is a fundamental difference between `import x` and `from x import y`. In both cases, file `x` will be run through and the code inside it will be executed - including any `print` statements, which makes sense. If you use `import x`, then the file `x` is executed, its namespace (including any function or variable definitions) is preserved, and a link to the module `x` is included in the namespace of the current file. If you use `from x import y`, the file `x` is executed, and then a *copy* of `y` is pasted into the namespace of the current file. You're essentially taking a snapshot of `two` at that point in time; any future changes `two` makes won't be reflected in `three`.

Let's head to the interpreter:

```
>>> execfile("two.py")     # This lets us run the file and keep the namespace
[1, 2]
[1, 2]
>>> id(test)
47312858429416
>>> id(three.test)
47312858429128
```

In this case, `test` is the variable that was created by `two.py`. Since the IDs are different, we can see that the `three` module created a copy of `test`, instead of referring to the actual object.

Now we can follow the program logic of `python two.py`. We start by creating `test = [1,2]`. Then `three.py` is executed. At this point, we have the line `from two import test`, and that will automatically run `two.py`, which will execute the `print` statement (resulting in `[1,2]`). This will also make a local copy of `test` for `three` to use. The `three` module then continues and appends 3, but *it only appends 3 to its local copy of `test`*. Then we go back to `two.py` to continue execution. When we print `test`, we're printing our local copy of it, which `three` never modified. That's how we get `[1,2]` a second time.

So here's where it gets tricky.

Take a look at the above `execfile` code again, and compare it to the code below, where instead of executing `python two.py`, I run `import two`:

```
>>> import two
[1, 2, 3]
>>> two.test
[1, 2, 3]
>>> two.three.test
[1, 2, 3]
>>> id(two.test)
47787298457576
>>> id(two.three.test)
47787298457576
```

This exploded my brain when I saw it, for two reasons. First off: we're no longer printing twice, only one time. Second: the `three` module no longer has a separate copy of `test`; it's now referring to the exact same object as `two` is.

The conclusion I came to is that **if you import `two.py` instead of executing it as the main file, Python will automatically resolve that circular reference, linking the `test` objects together and preventing `two` from executing multiple times.** When `three` tries to do the import, `two` detects that it is about to be imported again, and instead of executing that code again, it will simply give its copy of `test` to `three`. That's how I make sense of it, anyway.

This makes sense thinking about it, because otherwise you could end up with an infinite recursion loop. I'm sort of amazed that Python doesn't just slap the user for trying this circular weirdness, since it will catch other import problems that are similar, but this is a pretty good way of handling it as well.

But this explains the different behavior of `python one.py`. If you look at what happens with `from two import test`, it appears that we're seeing the "import" behavior from `two` instead of the "execution" behavior. Once that line of code is done, `two` contains a `test` object that contains `[1,2,3]`, and has printed it one time. That is then copied into `one`'s namespace and printed a second time. That's how we get that bizarre behavior.

So tl;dr: Python will execute your code differently depending on if you are executing a file normally or importing it. The different way we run `two` makes all the difference.  But **don't rely on Python resolving circular references in a reasonable manner**; this feels like gaming the system to me, and most of the time there will be a better way of designing your program to not have to deal with this confusion.

And with that, I'm taking a lunch break.

Comment: Thank you!

It's like rocket science :)

Comment: @warmspringwinds this is by far the most confusing Python-related thing I've done. But I came out with my sanity, at least.